# Why does this VHDL code work? 4:2 Priority encoder using Case statement

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, digital-logic

The code is below:

```
entity encoder_case is
 port(
     din : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
     dout : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0)
     );
end encoder_case;

architecture encoder_case_arc of encoder_case is
begin
encoder : process (din) is
begin
    case din is
        when "1000" => dout <= "00";
        when "0100" => dout <= "01";
        when "0010" => dout <= "10";
        when "0001" => dout <= "11";
        when others => dout <= "ZZ";
    end case;
end process encoder;
end encoder_case_arc;
```

Now you'd expect that this code does not cover cases suh as when din is "0101", "1010" etc. But for those inputs, dout produces "10" and "11" respectively. Why does this work? Does VHDL intelligently give higher priority to the higher order bits? Does it 'know' that we're trying to accomplish a priority encoder here?

Comment: Can you show TB code and waveforms?

Comment: That's not the behavior I show: [encoder_case_tb.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RBozz.png). That mid level yellow line represents Z's. You haven't provide an [Minimum Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your readers.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.9 Case statement introduces the matching case statement using the matching equality operator "?=" for comparing a choice against the case expression. *VHDL 2008 Just the New Stuff* by Ashenden and Lewis has [Example 5.7](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ3w9.jpg) using a matching case statement as a priority encoder. An ordinary case statement requires a match using the "=" operator and must be exact. The implicitly defined equality operators immediately following type declaration are used for the case expression/choice comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All cases under "others" should produce "ZZ", except if another signal would be driving dout. We will indeed need your testbench and waveforms to clarify this.

As for your other questions: There is no such thing as priority in a case, not in terms of the order of options and certainly not in the sense of higher/lower bits.

And it certainly does not "know" what you want to do. What you get is what you wrote, as always ... It might just take some time to understand what you exactly wrote sometimes.

Comment: I know its `vhdl` tag but just FYI: there is a priority case but in `verilog` / `system-verilog`

Comment: Hi Dawid. In VHDL the priority issue is off the table because of the requirement of all choices to be mutually exclusive and "others" to appear as the last option.

Comment: See the comment to the question on matching case statements  wherein VHDL has the capability of doing priority encoding in -2008 demonstrated in [Example 5.7](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ3w9.jpg) from the book *VHDL 2008 Just the New Stuff*.

Comment: @user1155120: Even though the result can be called a "priority arbiter", there is no priority among the options. How can one talk about priority when the choices are mutually exclusive? Or, put differently, what do you think would change if you would swap the order in which the options appear in Example 5.7?

Comment: Matching case choice expressions provide alternatives to populating an entire truth table with equality evaluated ("=") choice expressions, relying instead on matching equality ("?="). The difference is in how matching equality between case and choice expressions is defined populating a truth table with fewer choices using 'don't care' meta-matching. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.9 Case statement, paras 7,8.9, 11 and 9.2.3 Relational operators, matching equality ("?="). Example 5-7 choices can be reordered (it's the leading '0's, priority is choice value dependent not choice order).